# find the maximum unbalance of a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have the class Bintree that defines a binary tree. 
I need to implement a method that returns the maximum displacement of the nodes of the tree. 
So returns a pair of integers; the first of which is the height of t, the second is the maximum imbalance of the subtrees of t. 
With 'imbalance of a tree' I mean:

**imbalance of a tree** = *absolute value of the difference between the height of the left subtree and the height of the right subtree.*

I created the private inner class *IntPair* to contain the two integers. 
I know that the method is a recursive method, so I wrote the base case and I think it's correct. 
Instead I miss the recursive step... What I wrote is wrong. 
How do I find the maximum value?

```
public class BinTreeUtil {

    protected static class IntPair {
        int height;
        int maxUnbal;

        IntPair(int h, int u) {
            height = h; 
            maxUnbal = u;
        }
    }

    public static int maxUnbalance(BinTree t) {
        return heightUnbalance(t).maxUnbal;
    }

    private static IntPair heightUnbalance(BinTree t) {
        if(t == null) 
            return new IntPair(-1, 0);
        else {
            int sbil = Math.abs(height(t.left) + height(t.right));
            return new IntPair(height(t), ???);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to maintain both the height and the unbalance during the recursion :

```
private static IntPair heightUnbalance(BinTree t) {
    if(t == null) 
        return new IntPair(0, 0);
    else {
        IntPair leftResult = heightUnbalance(t.left);
        IntPair rightResult = heightUnbalance(t.right);
        return new IntPair(1+Math.max(leftResult.height,rightResult.height),
                           Math.abs(leftResult.height-rightResult.height));
    }
}
```

You want to maintain both the height and the unbalance during the recursion :

- The height of each node is 1 + the max height of the children.
- The imbalance of each node is the absolute value of the difference of heights of the children.
- For an empty node, you should return (0,0).